# RDP software with MFA?

Tags: 20.04, rdp

I have been suffering for long with Remmina and RDP connection. It turns out that Remmina does not support Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA), i.e. while connecting using RDP, I get a notification on my Phone on Microsoft authenticator to agree with the connection.

I could not find a RDP software which supports MFA. I prefer GUI instead of CLI. Does anyone have any suggestion?